# Variable invisible outside a function

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

I have written a query to get customer information from my database but say I want to use it on another page. I don't want to have to copy and paste to the other page to use it.

I have looked at a function but I don't know how to get the variables out of the function.

This is my current function:

```
function getCustomer($customerid) {

$getcustomer = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM hire_customers WHERE id='".$customerid."'");
$fetch = mysql_fetch_assoc($getcustomer);

$cust_firstname = $fetch['firstname'];
$cust_lastname =  $fetch['lastname'];
$cust_address =   $fetch['address'];
$cust_town =      $fetch['town'];
$cust_postcode =  $fetch['postcode'];
$cust_cont1 =     $fetch['contact1'];
$cust_number1 =   $fetch['contactnumber1'];
$cust_cont2 =     $fetch['contact2'];
$cust_number =    $fetch['contactnumber2'];
$cust_email =     $fetch['email'];
$cust_idform1 =   $fetch['idform1'];
$cust_idnfo1 =    $fetch['idinfo1'];
$cust_idform2 =   $fetch['idform2'];
$cust_idinfo2 =   $fetch['idinfo2'];
$cust_enterdby =  $fetch['enteredby']; 

}
```

This is my customer page

```
getCustomer($customerid);

echo $cust_firstname;
```

but nothing is echoed out.

Do I need to be looking at a class or object to do this? Have I gone wrong with my function.

What I would like to do is have a PHP file with all my customer functions (update, select, etc) in one place.

Comment: read to understand [what is veriable scope][1]  


  [1]: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

Comment: @GeorgeCummins that question title is terrible...

Comment: @Kamil, check the last line of the OP's original post: "_what i would like to do is have a php file with all my customer functions in, like update details, select details (one above) etc._" It title may not have been ideal, but it reflected the question as I understood it and was a good deal better than the original.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you should just return `$fetch` and then access it as a variable outside of the function.

```
function getCustomer($customerid) {
    $customerid = mysql_real_escape_string($customerid);
    $getcustomer = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM hire_customers WHERE id='".$customerid."'");
    $fetch = mysql_fetch_assoc($getcustomer);
    return $fetch;
}

$data=getCustomer($customerid);

echo data['firstname'];
```

Answer (score 3):

This should get you started:

```
function getCustomer($customerid) {

    $getcustomer = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM hire_.. etc");
    $customer_data = mysql_fetch_assoc($getcustomer);

    return $customer_data; // return here
}

$customer = getCustomer($customerid);

$cust_firstname = $customer['firstname'];
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to return a value from your function `return $variable;`

Answer (score 0):

In your code, variable `$cust_firstname;` is visible only inside that function.

Please read this: [PHP variable scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php)

It works like this to reduce memory usage on web server - when function ends - variable is destroyed and memory freed.

Basically - you have to `return` that value somehow. Dave Chen wrote nice answer above/below, you can use his code.

---

BTW you can use [extract();](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php) function and reduce your code size and save a lot of time.

It works like this:

```
$fetch = mysql_fetch_assoc($getcustomer);

extract($fetch, EXTR_PREFIX_ALL, "cust_"); // creates variables from associative array

echo $cust_firstname; // magic! :)
```